# What is the probablistic distribution of exponential convolution of a Gaussian white noise process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Say $x(t)$ is a Gaussian white noise process with $\sigma^2$ as variance.

Now what is the probabilistic distribution of $Y(t)$?

$$ Y(t) = \int_{0}^t x(s) e^{a(t-s)} ds $$

say $a \in \mathbb{R}$. **I want to know the PDF.**

### What I know

when $a = 0$, $Y(t)$ is Wiener process and I know the PDF.

Comment: Oh.  I think I have found the solution.. I should take some course in stochastic process... https://www.arpm.co/lab/multiv-ornstein-uhlenbeck.html